# Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting

Tags: hosting, moodle

I created moodle site in infinity free hosting
But when I open the site it is appear this message

Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.

Comment: Ask vendor or consult their documentation.  Removed the free and infinity tag as it refers to something else.  If you seek help with moodle post a [mre].

Comment: If you can create the directory yourself, then there are some instructions here https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Installing_Moodle#Create_the_.28moodledata.29_data_directory - otherwise contact your host

Answer (score 0):

Probably a permissions issue on your directories or files. Or a wrong path.

Check the following:

1. Open file `config.php` and check if the given path for `$CFG->dataroot` really exists on your server.
2. Make sure the folder `moodledata` is writable (permission 777).
3. Make sure all files and all database tables have been copied completely.

You can edit `config.php` and enable the debugging part `@ini_set('display_errors', '1');` to see any errors.